# SOQL on EntityDefinition not returning expected result

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api

I am trying to understand why the following SOQL is not applying the filtering criteria.

```
SELECT QualifiedAPIName, internalsharingmodel FROM EntityDefinition WHERE internalsharingmodel != 'Private'
```

However when I execute the below block using anonymous apex

```
List<EntityDefinition> entities = [SELECT internalsharingmodel, QualifiedAPIName FROM EntityDefinition];
for (EntityDefinition e : entities){
    if (e.internalsharingmodel != 'Private'){
        system.debug(e.QualifiedAPIName + ' , ' +e.internalsharingmodel);
    }
}
```

I am able to achieve the expected outcome of filtering internal sharing model with values that are not **Private**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm

InternalSharingModel
Type
picklist
Properties
Filter, Group, Restricted picklist, Sort
Description
The internal sharing model. Possible values are:
None
Read
Edit
ControlledByLeadOrContact
ControlledByCampaign
This field is available in Tooling API version 38.0 and later.

Comment: What unexpected outcome are you obtaining? Please [edit] to add detail.

Comment: @DavidReed I was able to confirm this behavior. I believe it is a bug, as the API call should return None, Edit, etc, not Private, etc... and the describe call confirms the names don't match the labels, but the filters don't seem to work either way (api name or label), both in the REST and Tooling API queries.

Comment: @DavidReed I am just trying to filter the result set to get a list of QualifiedAPIName that have sharingmodel = 'Private', as you can see != is not supported for EntityDefinition, however = is not yielding any results.

The API documentation says, the values for nonsharinmodel should be 'None','Read','Edit' however this not what is getting returned by the API.

Comment: ya SOQL queries on this object just seem straight up broken.  `WHERE NamespacePrefix = null` filters out all records